# What should have javadoc in Java?

Tags: java, javadoc, conventions

What should be documented by javadoc comments (classes, methods, constructors and fields? Or only classes methods and constructors?)? Is there any convention about that ?

Please provide links to relevant resources in your answer whenever possible.
Thank you

**EDIT:** The question is not about how is it usualy done or what is logical to comment with javadoc. The question is what can be found about this matter in any official Sun/Oracle documents (guidelines about writing javadoc, conventions, specifications and so on). Also please do not answer about how should the javadoc comments look like, the question is specifically about what should be commented, not how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javadoc is to document the public API of your code.

In a nutshell, you need to document all your public and protected classes, methods, constructors, and fields (because they are accessible to your users).

You need to describe what a method does, not how it does it. Of course, if implementation details result in interesting side-effects, for example performance characteristics, and also usage limitations, those should be mentioned.

Oracle has official guidelines on "[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)".

Comment: Please see edit of the question. I know what it should look like, I just need to know if there are some conventions, official guidelines or rules on what should be commented.

Answer (score 4):

Simple and general rules for javadoc as mentioned by Thilo and also from [here](http://wiki.statsbiblioteket.dk/domswiki/Javadoc%20Guidelines) should be as follows :

> **Javadoc Guidelines**
>
> **General Rules**
>
> - All public and protected methods must    have full documentation
> - Trivial getters and setters are    exempted from this rule. Doing
>     anything but returning or changing a
>     variable in a getter or setter should 
>     be documented.
> - Private methods with non-obvious    implementations should have enough
>     documentation to allow other
>     developers to debug them

Official guidelines are found here : [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: Getters and setters merit documentation as well. Can they return or accept null? What does the property mean? How does it affect the behavior of the object or class?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine showing the code to someone else who is familiar with the programming language, but not your project.  Whichever parts you feel the need to explain as you're watching him review it should be documented.

similar question on programmers.SE: [Should you document everything or just most?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/10857/4475)

Comment: If you are talking about code review or getting a new programmer up to speed with the code base, I don't think this is what JavaDoc is for.

Comment: @Thilo it was just an example for helping people decide when they've documented "enough", but the edit sounds like he's asking something a little different